# Bibliographic references in LaTeX

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

How you can write references as I want

> [ref1 and ref2]

I know that we can write as `\cite{1,2}`, but I need the output to be be [1 and 2], not [1,2].

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report} 
\begin{document} 
we have transform from $ A : f \rightarrow g $ \cite{1 and 2} 

\begin{thebibliography}{30} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography} 
\bibitem{1} D. Arcoya, \emph{An Introduction to Problems}, Springer, 2011. 
\bibitem{2} Nassor, \emph{On the Uniqueness}, pages 377-390, (1992). 
\end{thebibliography} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simplify your work you can also work with `biblatex`. To complete the answer here an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[style=numeric,sortcites]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}%
    \ifbool{bbx:subentry}%
      {\printfield{entrysetcount}}%
   \ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}-1}%
       {\gdef\multicitedelim{\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}}%
       {\gdef\multicitedelim{\addcomma\space}}%
    }%
}
\begin{document} 
\cite{companion,ctan,knuth:ct:a}

\cite{companion,ctan,knuth:ct:a}


\cite{companion,ctan}

\cite{knuth:ct:a}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It need the compilation

```
pdflatex
biber
pdflatex
pdflatex
```

---

You can use the package `cite` with a minor modification. Define a command `citeduo` where the separator is `and` instead of `,`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage{cite}
\newcommand*\citeduo[1]{%
 \bgroup%
   \def\citepunct{\ and\ }%
   \cite{#1}%
  \egroup%
}
\begin{document} 
we have transform from $ A : f \rightarrow g $ \citeduo{Arcoya,Nassor} 

\begin{thebibliography}{30} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography} 
\bibitem{Arcoya} D. Arcoya, \emph{An Introduction to Problems}, Springer, 2011. 
\bibitem{Nassor} Nassor, \emph{On the Uniqueness}, pages 377-390, (1992). 
\end{thebibliography} 
\end{document}
```

However for all your previous projects I recommend `biblatex` with an external `bib-file`.

---

**EDIT**

Modified version to separat cite's:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \mathcal_cite_clist
\NewDocumentCommand \mycite { m }
 {
  \group_begin:
   \citeleft  
    \int_compare:nNnTF { \clist_count:n { #1 }  } = { 1 } 
       { \citen { #1 } }
       { 
        \clist_set:No \mathcal_cite_clist { #1 }
        \mathcal_output_cite:  
       }
   \citeright
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new:Npn \mathcal_output_cite:
 {
  \int_compare:nNnTF { \clist_count:N \mathcal_cite_clist } = { 2 }
    { \mathcal_output_duo_cite:n { \mathcal_cite_clist }  }
    {
      \clist_gpop:NN \mathcal_cite_clist \l_tmpa_tl
      \citen { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl } \citepunct
      \mathcal_output_cite:
    }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \mathcal_output_duo_cite:n  #1 
 {
 \group_begin:
   \def\citepunct{\ and\ }
   \citen{ #1 }
  \group_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*\citeduo[1]{%
 \bgroup%
   \def\citepunct{\ and\ }%
   \citen{#1}%
  \egroup%
}
\begin{document} 
we have transform from $ A : f \rightarrow g $ \mycite{Arcoya,Nassor,temp} 

\mycite{Arcoya,Nassor} 

\mycite{Arcoya} 

\begin{thebibliography}{30} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography} 
\bibitem{Arcoya} D. Arcoya, \emph{An Introduction to Problems}, Springer, 2011. 
\bibitem{Nassor} Nassor, \emph{On the Uniqueness}, pages 377-390, (1992). 
\bibitem{temp} temp
\end{thebibliography} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: owww, sorry for this comment but its right just for 2 references if we have three it can not do the best, for example, [1,2 and 3]

Comment: or some times we have [1,3 and 7] so I want for this situation if you can, thanks very much

Comment: sorry I can not understand what you mean by biblatex ? :(

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management, also I read this but :(

Comment: yeh, but they give us just more Style not the multiple \cite

Comment: well done dear Marco, that is I talk about it, thank you very very much

Comment: @Mathcal: Please see my new edit.